# SQL Server accessing rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a database where one table is as follows:

```
Owner Type | Owner Name
---------------------------------
Testing    | abc, def, xyz
Testing2   | ppp
Testing3   | jkl, mno, pqr
```

In the SQL Report (SSRS), I would like to display something like this:

```
Testing owners = abc, def, xyz
Testing2 owners = ppp
Testing3 owners = jkl,m mno, pqr
```

How do I build a report in this way, using SQL Server Report Builder?
I understand that a simply query would work using the regular SQL Query mode. However, the difficulty I am facing is that there is only a single table cell where I need to enter the expression to be evaluated (there are more things in the table and the report, this is only a subset). I'm not sure how I can get that done.

Comment: Seems straight forward to me.. What exactly is the problem? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Well, getting the appropriate results in SQL Server is easy, since a query like:
     Select Owner Name from table where Owner Type = 'Testing'
would be fine.
However, in SSRS, there is only 1 text box that contains the expression to be evaluated. I don't know how to iterate through each row with a corresponding mapping.

Comment: Did you create a dataset in SSRS with the query you used in SQL Server? You can then map the columns [Owner Type] and [Owner Name] to a Table / Tablix / whatever output you need. Or is your question how to get the two columns to display (concatenate) in one cell?

Comment: So these test owners are for a particular object. The owners would change when the object changes. In the report, I would have to display all objects, along with their test owners, when the user selects that object. As a result, I'm not sure how to make the dataset, considering that it's dynamic.

Comment: Could you post the query you have right now? You could create a dataset with parameters that is dependent on variables in your report for example

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT Owner_Type, Owner_Name FROM [dbo].[Own]. That's all I have at the moment. :(

Comment: Ok, but do you have a `WHERE` clause to filter the set by `the objects the user selects` as you say it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you

```
SELECT [Owner Type], [Owner Name] FROM Table
```

You can group by [Owner type] in a table/matrix in your SSRS report and get something that looks like

```
Testing
Testing2
Testing3
```

Then you can add what you need after that on a new column f.ex. But grouping is the way to display all [Owner type].

Edit: Suggestion to filter:
[image]

Comment: This is true. But this set of owners is for a particular object. When the object changes, the owners change as well. I have a landing page where a summary of all the objects are given. If I click on one object, it should open another page where the test owners (as shown above) are displayed. How would I make it considering the various objects too?

Comment: What is the relationship between your object and owners? You should probably be able to send the object as a parameter to the report showing owners and filter the owner report using the object value sent.

Comment: Yes, exactly. I know how to do it in SQL, not in SQL Report Builder. That's the issue!

Comment: Is the object landing page you are talking about also a report? Create a parameter in you Owner report. Create an action in the object report (if it's a report) and send down the value of the object. I would extend the dataset you create for owner to also include the object so you have an easy connection. and then use filter on your group.

Comment: Added a screenshot of how I would have created the filter if you extend the dataset to include object and create a parameter in your report to recieve the object value from your landing report.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 2 ways to do this

I would recommend doing the catenation in the report itself. Assuming you have already used the wizard to create the dataset, and the wizard has both `raw` columns in your report already, right click on the `OwnerType` detail row text box and select [`Expression (fx)`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220516.aspx). You can then project the required display, e.g.:

```
=Fields!Owner_Type.Value + " owners = " + Fields!Owner_Name.Value
```

And then change the column name and delete the second column entirely.

The other way to do this is by projecting this directly in a Sql Query, e.g. by providing the following query by using the configure option on the `DataSource:`

```
select Owner_Type + ' owners = ' + Owner_Name as OwnerRow
from [dbo].[Own];
```

(you could also create a proc or view in SqlServer to do this projection and then bind the report to the proc / view).